# Multiply 2 values from 2 different tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to multiply value X by value Y with SQL. Value X is located in table A and B is located in table B. I couldn't find the answer for this.

**Table Transactions**

```
ID Transaction_ID Total_Amount
1  001            1200
2  002            1500
3  003            1600
```

**Table Rates**

```
ID Currency_Name Exchange_Rate
1  AUD           1.5
2  SEK           2.0
3  PLN           3.0
```

The question I'm trying to answer is:

What is the Total_Amount for transaction 001 in SEK (Swedish Crown). So I need to multiply 1200 * 2.0 and display the result.

Comment: You need to supply more information, table structure (with foreign keys).

Comment: you can multiply values in different tables using [joins](http://databases.about.com/od/careers/l/aajoins1.htm) like this `SELECT table_1.x * table_2.y FROM table_1, table_2 WHERE table_1.primaryKey = table_2.primaryKey`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited based on added info**

```
SELECT Total_Amount * Exchange_Rate AS Value 
FROM Transactions, Rates 
WHERE Rates.Currency_Name = 'Sek' and Transaction_id = 001
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

> What is the Total_Amount for
>   transaction 001 in SEK (Swedish
>   Crown). So I need to multiply 1200 *
>   2.0 and display the result.

Use:

```
SELECT ID, Transaction_ID, Total_Amount, Total_Amount*(SELECT Exchange_Rate from Rates where Currency_Name='SEK') 
FROM TRANSACTIONS
WHERE TRANSACTION_ID='001'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, depending on your table structure :

```
select table1.x * table2.y
from table1, table2;
```

But I actually doubt that this is really what you want to do, if you provide more information, we could give you a much better answer. Please provide table structure and you're real goal !

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. I have provided more detailed description. @TBohnen.jnr @Harry @Krtek

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
select a.x*b.y from tableA a, tableB b
```