# compare two tables and update the third one

Tags: c#, sql

Suppose I have a table in SQL **"abc"** and with in it there is a column "number" and this column contains (1,2,3,4) etc.

In my second table **"xyz"** I have a column "number" and this column contains (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).

Now I want to compare these two and insert equal data within third table.
So how can I do this?

code :

```
string str = "SELECT     Invoice_Details.PGI_ID, PARTY_BOOKING_DETAILS.PGI_ID AS abc ";
str += "FROM         PARTY_BOOKING_MAIN INNER JOIN ";
str += "    PARTY_BOOKING_DETAILS ON PARTY_BOOKING_MAIN.PBM_ID = PARTY_BOOKING_DETAILS.PBM_ID CROSS JOIN ";
str += "          Invoice_Details where PARTY_BOOKING_MAIN.PM_ID = 1 ";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source = .; database = ePartyDatabase01; integrated security = true");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update Invoice_Details set [status] = @a", con);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    if (dr["PGI_ID"].ToString() == dr["abc"].ToString())
    {

        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", 1);

    }
}

dr.Close();
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

Comment: check the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602083/sql-compare-data-from-two-tables

Comment: Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990586/mulitply-2-values-from-2-different-tables

Comment: to be clear, in the 3rd table you would insert 1,2,3,4?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use some kind of this query:

```
insert into table3 (number)
select 
    t1.number
from abc t1
inner join xyz t2
    on t1.number = t2.number
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet, but you might not even need C#, try something like this:

```
SELECT xyz.number
INTO third_table
FROM (
   SELECT t1.number
   FROM first_table t1 JOIN second_table t2 ON t1.number = t2.number
) AS xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table3(number)
SELECT
    number
FROM
    xyz
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            abc
        WHERE
            abc.number=xyz.number
    )
```