# multiply values from 2 tables sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and want to multiply values together if they satisfy a condition. I looked at [Multiply 2 values from 2 different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990586/multiply-2-values-from-2-different-tables?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
to no avail

I want to multiply all values in #Temp1 with the corresponding value from #Temp2 where the month from #Temp1 is the same as the month from #Temp2.

I tried

`select costs * ratio as Value
from #Temp1, #Temp2
where #Temp2.ratio = cast(SUBSTRING(#Temp1.date,5,2)as int)`

to no avail

I want:

```
costs  date  ratio
234.33 20170103 23.433
56.65  20170203 11.33
```

I am working with SQL Server2012, and any help will be appreciated.

```
Table #Temp1
234.33  20170103
56.65   20170203

Table #Temp2
0.1 1
0.2 2
0.3 3   


IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL

    DROP TABLE #Temp1

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Temp2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp2

create table #Temp1
(
    costs float, 
    date Varchar(50) 
)

create table #Temp2
(
    ratio float, 
    month int 
)


insert into #Temp1 
values (234.33, 20170103)

insert into #Temp1 
values (56.65, 20170203)

insert into #Temp2 
values (.1,01)
insert into #Temp2 
values (.2,02)
insert into #Temp2 
values (.3,03)

select ratio from #Temp2 where month=3
select cast(SUBSTRING(date,5,2)as int) as month from #Temp1

select * from #Temp1
select * from #Temp2
select costs * ratio as Value
from #Temp1, #Temp2
where #Temp2.ratio = cast(SUBSTRING(#Temp1.date,5,2)as int)
```

Comment: you should have used date datatype to store date in table1

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, it should be :

```
where #Temp2.month = cast(SUBSTRING(#Temp1.date,5,2)as int)
```

Instead :

```
where #Temp2.ratio = cast(SUBSTRING(#Temp1.date,5,2)as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bonehead.

it was a typo:

```
select *, costs * ratio as Value
from #Temp1, #Temp2
where #Temp2.month = cast(SUBSTRING(#Temp1.date,5,2)as int)
```

works

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Try now and give me remarks.

```
select month , case when #Temp2.month = cast(SUBSTRING(#Temp1.date,5,2)as int) then costs * ratio else null End as Value
from #Temp1 
left join #Temp2 on 
#Temp2.month = cast(SUBSTRING(#Temp1.date,5,2)as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was minor typo but the panic one, used `ratio` instead of `date` in the comparison

Above change will resolve your problem but still you can follow the few other major things

1.Avoid using keywords as column names as `date, month`

2.You don't need to cast the value in `INT` because it's implicitly converted before comparison

```
select t1.costs, 
    t1.date,
    (costs * ratio) as ratio
from #Temp1 t1
INNER JOIN #Temp2 t2 ON t2.month = SUBSTRING(t1.date,5,2)
```